# tinyMCE: tinymce.dom.Selection Events

Tags: dom, tinymce

Does someone used tinymce.dom.Selection class in tinyMCE? I'm unsuccessfully trying to apply a function to dom.Selection.onBeforeSetContent or onSetContent. The documentation shows the following syntax:

```
event_callback(<tinymce.dom.Selection> ed, <Object> o)
```

There's no neat example of its implementation. I'm in a hurry and tend to give up.

What i have already tried so far is:

```
$('#tinyMce').tinymce({
   ...
   setup: function(ed) {
      ed.dom.Selection.onSetContent.add(function(se,o){...});
   }
});
```

which fails with "ed.dom is undefined". I also tried:

```
$('#tinyMce').tinymce({
   ...
   init_instance_callback : "CustomInitInstance"
});

function CustomInitInstance(inst){
 //inst.dom.Selection.on... fails with "inst.dom is undefined"
 tinymce.dom.Selection.onBeforeSetContent.add(function(se,o){...}); // fails with "tinymce.dom.Selection.onBeforeSetContent is undefined"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ed.selection.onBeforeSetContent.add(function(se, o) {
        alert(o.content);
});
```

The above should fire an alert containing the content to be inserted if you paste it into your first example

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#tinyMce').tinymce({
   ...
   setup: function(ed) {
      ed.onInit.add(function(ed, o) {
        ed.selection.onBeforeSetContent.add(function(se,o){
          alert(o.content);
        });
      });
   }
});
```

it works before calling `ed.selection.setContent('my text')`

```
alert (o.content); // display  'my text'
```